# Only first item rendered in infinite scrolling banner

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an infinitely looping image banner but it seems that after adding an image overlay on hover, only the first item of the `scroll-element` divs seem to render. Inspecting the element tells me that the width of the rendered item is the same as the sum of all child elements, yet the only one who displays is the first one.

The issue appeared after i have added the `overlay-container` and `img-overlay` classes to overlay text over the scrolling pictures.

Here is my code:

## HTML:

```html
<div class="scroll-parent">
  <div class="scroll-element primary">
    <a class="overlay-container" href="">
      <img src="Pictures/Exterior1.jpg">
      <div class="img-overlay">35 Chem Meredith</div>
    </a>
    <a class="overlay-container" href="">
      <img src="Pictures/Exterior1.jpg">
      <div class="img-overlay">50 Chem Meredith</div>
    </a>
    <a class="overlay-container" href="">
      <img src="Pictures/Exterior1.jpg">
      <div class="img-overlay">35 Chem Meredith</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-element secondary">
    <a class="overlay-container" href="">
      <img src="Pictures/Exterior1.jpg">
      <div class="img-overlay">35 Chem Meredith</div>
    </a>
    <a class="overlay-container" href="">
      <img src="Pictures/Exterior1.jpg">
      <div class="img-overlay">50 Chem Meredith</div>
    </a>
    <a class="overlay-container" href="">
      <img src="Pictures/Exterior1.jpg">
      <div class="img-overlay">35 Chem Meredith</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

## CSS:

```css
.scroll-parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.scroll-parent::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100vw; height: 500px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 15%,   rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 85%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 15%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 75%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 85%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 15%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 75%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 85%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 );
}

.scroll-element {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.scroll-element img {
  width: auto;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.scroll-element img:hover {
  scale: 1.05;
}

.primary {
  animation: primary 5s linear infinite;
}

.secondary {
  animation: secondary 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes primary {
  from {
    left: 0%;
  }
  to {
    left: -100%;
  }
}

@keyframes secondary {
  from {
    left: 100%;
  }
  to {
    left: 0%;
  }
}

.overlay-container{
  position: absolute;
}

.img-overlay {
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0; 
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Black see-through */
  color: #f1f1f1; 
  width: 100%;
  transition: .2s ease;
  opacity:0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.overlay-container:hover .img-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Here is the picture I used if it could be useful https://ibb.co/DGpwkvD

I honestly can't find what could be causing the issue.

Comment: All your anchors are absolutely positioned without a defined left-top-right-bottom value. The browser will therefore estimate each of the boxes' positions by adding left (with default 0), margin-left, border-left for its left position, same for top position, resulting in all boxes sitting on top of one another. So in fact they all show up, but stacked on top of one another.

Comment: Thank you, changing '.overlay-container' from absolute to relative fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed

```css
.overlay-container{
  position: absolute;
}
```

to

```css
.overlay-container{
  position: relative;
}
```

which fixed the issue.